# Creating an HTML form basing on information extracted from an SQL database using while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to create a form, basing on information picked from the database using a while loop. I need some guidance on how to go about this. When form is supposed to return multiple values (of students) and then a text field for inputting marks is assigned to the students returned, which should allow the user input the marks and then submit the form.

Here is the code i have sofar

```
        <form method="post">
        <?php
          //picking student details
            $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * 
            FROM student, class, subject, assesment
            WHERE 
            student.class_id = '$assesment_class' 
            AND subject.idsubject = '$assesment_subject' 
            AND subject.subject_option = 'Major' 
            AND class.idclass = student.class_id
            AND class.idclass = subject.class_id
            AND assesment.subject_idsubject = subject.idsubject
            AND assesment.idassesment = '$ass'
            ");
                $Count = mysql_num_rows($sql); //counting the the selected rows

                if($Count > 0){

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                    //picking database values
                    $student_id = $row["idstudent"];
                    $student_names = $row["student_names"];

                             //Query for checking results 
                                $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                                FROM result, student_has_result, grade, student, assesment
                                WHERE 
                                student_has_result.student_id = '$student_id' 
                                AND student_has_result.student_class_id = '$assesment_class' 
                                AND student_has_result.assesment_id = '$ass' 
                                AND student_has_result.result_id = result.idresult 
                                AND result.grade_idgrade = grade.idgrade 
                                AND student_has_result.assesment_id = assesment.idassesment 
                                AND student_has_result.student_id = student.idstudent 
                                AND student_has_result.result_id = result.idresult");

                                    $Count1 = mysql_num_rows($sql1); //counting the the selected rows

                                    if($Count1 > 0){
                                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)){
                                        //picking database values
                                        $mark = $row["mark"];

                                        //echo $mark; 

                                       }
                                    }else{
                                    $mark = "";
                                    }

                            ?>      

                    <tr>
                     <td><?php echo $student_names; ?></td>

                     <td>
                     <input type="text" name="result" placeholder="<?php echo $mark; ?>"/>
                     <input type="hidden" name="student" value="<?php echo $student_id; ?>"/>
                     <input type="hidden" name="assesment" value="<?php echo $ass; ?>"/>
                     </td>
                    </tr>



                    <?php
                   }
                   ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><button name="submit-results-button" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">-Submit Students Results Now-</button><br><br></td>
                    </tr>
                </form>
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Look into arrays in php: `<input type="text" name="result[<?php echo $student_id; ?>]" placeholder="<?php echo $mark; ?>"/>`. `foreach ($_POST['result'] as $student_id => $mark ) { /* Loop here */ }`